# How to set a predefined DNS/Address for EKS Ingress

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I used the following guide to set up the Ingress Controller in my Fargate Cluster:

```
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-alb-ingress-controller-fargate/
```

In my Ingress, I used these annotations:

```
annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internal
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name: my-ingress
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: my-group
```

When I get the Ingress I see the following:

```
internal-my-ingress-XXXXXXXXXX.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com
```

I want to know if there is a way to replace those numbers (XXXXXXXXX) with a predefined value because I don't want to see the address changes if I delete and create the Ingress.